# Eclipse incorrect project location on disk

Tags: java, eclipse, path, eclipse-juno

I had a problem with Eclipse Juno due to my workspace name and the project name being the same. So I created a new workspace and imported projects to the new one. But when I go to the project's properties (in the new workspace), it is showing the path to my old workspace on the disk. How do I solve this?

Comment: If you use Import Project Wizard you have to check Copy Projects into workspace check box (I use Indigo, but I imagine Juno will have the same).

Comment: yes that option is there in Juno as well. But if you miss it how do you change the path after?

Comment: try File-> Import->General->File System. After that update source references or delete project (without deleting the files) and recreate it (that would be cleaner)

Answer (score 0):

why not just open .classpath and .project files in notepad and take a look at what values are pointing to old location and just change them to new paths as relevant.